# How can I get the public tx key on private testnet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, testnet, transaction-key

I built a private testnet with reference to https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet.
I want to check the public tx key of the issued tx, but I don't know how to check it.
I cannot use https://xmrchain.net/tx/[tx_id] because I use a private testnet.
How can I check the public tx key?

Answer (score 2):

The public tx key is contained in the extra field. You can use monero-utils-deserialize to decode it from the transaction's hexadecimal representation, which you can get from the daemon, like this:

In monerod:

> print_tx TXID +hex

(replace TXID with your transaction's txid)

Then, in a shell:

> monero-utils-deserialize --input DATA

(replace data with the output from the previous monerod command)

If the transaction contains a tx public key (and the vast majority do), it will be printed out.

Note that monero-utils-deserialize is only built for debug builds.